# What story has a soldier in Vietnam using drug-fuelled hallucinations to defeat an egg-shaped alien invader?

Tags: story-identification

The premise of this one is admittedly odd, but hopefully that will help someone remember it.

A free-wheeling hippy type has been drafted into Vietnam.  This hasn't stopped his counter-culture ways, as he has taken LSD prior to going on patrol in the jungle.  I believe the soldier becomes separated from the rest of his unit, and in the process discovers a malevolent alien that looks kind of like a big egg (IIRC).

The egg-alien seems to feed upon thoughts or perhaps mental energy.  I'm not sure on that point.  I do remember that the soldier realizes the creature is a threat, and begins to use his imagination (and his altered state) to create wild hallucinations to overpower the alien creature.  In doing so, he realizes he is losing his own creative spirit, and fears he might end up being a "square."   In the end, he prevails over the alien creature with one massive final hallucination, which caused the creature to explode, leaving "splattered egg" everywhere.

The final paragraph takes places a few years later.  He's a banker or something now, wears a suit and tie, drinks scotch and so on.  The twist being, he became the establishment-type he loathed before his encounter with "The Egg."

I thought this might be a Spider Robinson story, but I have not been able to find anything under his name that fits.  Any guesses?

Thanks in advance, and apologies if this is a duplicate.  I searched for a good while and found nothing matching this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

["Overdose"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?51703) by [Spider Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_Robinson), first published in [*Galaxy*, September 1975](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58660+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v36n08_1975-09#page/n143/mode/2up).

**A free-wheeling hippy type has been drafted into Vietnam. This hasn't stopped his counter-culture ways, as he has taken LSD prior to going on patrol in the jungle.**

Actually he took [STP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,5-Dimethoxy-4-methylamphetamine), which seems to be a slang term for a kind of hallucinogenic drug:

> Six hours later I was back in the jungle. I had a pair of pants, some four and a half bricks from the General's private stash, a compass, two Dylan albums and (although I was not to know it for weeks) a heavy dose of clap. I felt great, and it was all thanks to General Fonebone. If Suzy had not found life in Vietnam so boring, she would never have gone rummaging and uncovered the General's Secret Stash, a fell collection of strange tabs and arcane caps. She had induced me to swallow  the largest single tab in the bunch, an immense purple thing with a skull embossed on it above the lone word: "HEAVY," and it appeared in retrospect to have been a triple tab of STP cut with ibogaine, benzedrine, coke and just a touch of Bab-O.

**I believe the soldier becomes separated from the rest of his unit, and in the process discovers a malevolent alien that looks kind of like a big egg (IIRC).**

> And just before I hit, I saw something coming over the rise, and I knew that my mind had truly blown at last.
>
> Coming toward me was a sixteen-foot-tall poached egg with pimples.

**The egg-alien seems to feed upon thoughts or perhaps mental energy.**

> *This world would simply have to serve. Somewhere on this planet must exist a life-form of sufficient vitality to fill Yteic-Os's reserve cells with The Force, and heshe was not called The Voracious for nothing.* [. . . .] *Yes, no doubt of it, a sentient life-form, just brimming with The Force! Yteic-Os sent a guarded probe, yelped with joy (well, not precisely) as heshe learned that this planet was crawling with sentient beings. What a bountiful harvest!*

**[The soldier] realizes he is losing his own creative spirit, and fears he might end up being a "square."**

> I was being drained of originality, of wit, of inventiveness, of all the things that made life groovy. I had a grim vision of myself a few years hence, a short-haired square working in a factory living contentedly in Scarsdale with a frigid wife and a neurotic Pekingese, stumbling over the Cryptoquote in the *Daily News* and drinking Black Label before the T.V. A grimmer vision I can't imagine, but I still missed it when, with a sucking sound, it disappeared into the poached egg.

**I do remember that the soldier realizes the creature is a threat, and begins to use his imagination (and his altered state) to create wild hallucinations to overpower the alien creature.**

> Desperately I rammed my forebrain into low gear and cut in the afterburner. I dug into the tangled whorls of my cerebrum for all the creativity that heredity and environment had given me, and began to hallucinate as fast and as intricately as I could. I prayed that the poached egg would O.D.

**In the end, he prevails over the alien creature with one massive final hallucination, which caused the creature to explode, leaving "splattered egg" everywhere.**

> And when I could see again, there was scrambled eggs all over the place.

**The final paragraph takes places a few years later. He's a banker or something now, wears a suit and tie, drinks scotch and so on. The twist being, he became the establishment-type he loathed before his encounter with "The Egg."**

> I live a perfectly content life now that the war is over. Got me a wife, a nice little one-family in Scarsdale that I'll have entirely paid off in another twenty-five years, and a steady job down at the distributing plant—I get to bring home unlimited quantities of Black Label.
>
> But sometimes I drink a little too much of it, and my wife Mabel says when I'm drunk—aside from becoming "disgustingly physical"—I often babble a lot. Something about having saved the world. . . .